# java: incompatible types: historical.Historical<R> cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends historical.Historical<R>

Tags: java, generics

Here is my 2 methods:

```java
    public <R> Historical<R> flatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends Historical<R>> f) {
        Optional<? extends Historical<R>> historical = map(f).get();
        Historical<R> empty = new Historical<>(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty());
        return foo(historical.orElse(empty));


//        throw new RuntimeException("Historical::flatMap has not been implemented yet!");
    }
    private <R> Historical<R> foo(Historical<R> head){
        return new Historical<>();
    }
```

I think the `historical` variable has a generic type as `<? extends Historical<R>>`. However, when I try to use `historical.orElse(empty)`, the IDE has prompt as following:

```
Required type:
capture of ? extends Historical<R>

Provided:
Historical      <R>
```

Base on my shallow java knowledge, I thought `Historical<R>` itself is a capture of `? extends Historical<R>`

Can someone explain a little bit about why it is happening, and how i should fix it probably?

Comment: The required type is not “a” capture of `? extends Historical<R>` but one particular (unknown) capture. There’s practically nothing you can pass to the method at this point. Your mistake is to let the wildcard type slip in. You didn’t show the class declaration itself nor the definition of the `map` method, but the following might work: `Optional<Historical<R>> historical = this.<Historical<R>>map(f).get();` If not, show the class definition and the `map` method…

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're encountering is due to the way Java handles generics and type inference, especially when dealing with wildcard types (? extends T). Let's break down the problem and see how to fix it.

In your flatMap method, you have the following line:

```
Optional<? extends Historical<R>> historical = map(f).get();
```

Here, map(f).get() returns an Optional with a wildcard type that extends Historical. However, when you call historical.orElse(empty), you're trying to provide an instance of Historical, not a wildcard type that extends Historical. This is causing the type mismatch error.

To fix this issue, you can change the type of empty to match the wildcard type. Since empty is essentially an empty Historical, you can declare it as Historical<? extends R> empty = new Historical<>(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty());. This way, it matches the wildcard type, and the error should be resolved.

Here's how you can modify your code:

```
public <R> Historical<R> flatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends Historical<R>> f) {
    Optional<? extends Historical<R>> historical = map(f).get();
    Historical<? extends R> empty = new Historical<>(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty());
    return foo(historical.orElse(empty));
}

private <R> Historical<R> foo(Historical<R> head){
    return new Historical<>();
}
```

By changing the type of empty to Historical<? extends R>, it matches the wildcard type, and the error should be resolved.